# Can't compile quake 3 arena source code

Tags: c++, crash, quake

I need help compiling the source code for Quake III Arena. I'm using the version provided by ID Software's Github account (https://github.com/id-Software/Quake-III-Arena). I'm trying to compile it in VS2015, is that a problem? It converts the project without any issues. However, when I compile, all I get is a black screen and a messed up color scheme. The debugger tells me the problem is in this funcion:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    __asm  {
        pushad
        mov     esi, programStack;
        mov     edi, opStack
        call    entryPoint
        mov     programStack, esi
        mov     opStack, edi
        popad
    }
```

More precisely, in the line `mov programStack, esi`. Any ideas? I'm trying to make a game with this engine, since it's basically the "mother" of all Fpses today :D
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's a maintained fork of that code (ioq3) that's probably easier to use.

Comment: I know about ioquake3, i just wanted to mess around the original code to learn how it was done and implement stuff on my own.

Comment: If you're saying that ***compiling*** the program results in a crash, that's either due to a bug in your compiler, or, based on the symptoms you've described, your hardware is bad.

Comment: I don't think the problem is my hardware - GTX760, AMD FX4300. Can't see why that would be an issue. I've been trying to compile the program for quite some time, maybe it's "persistently glitched"? As a restart couldn't fix it?

Comment: Is compilation or execution the problem?

Comment: I guess i didn't express myself well: the program actually compiles, but as soon as it runs the game triggers a breakpoint in the code mentioned

Comment: If you can't debug this, you really should be using a maintained codebase like ioq3. I have hacked on Quake mods and engines for 15 years, and I can tell you from experience that there is no nobility in going it alone. You're not going to miss out on any valuable experience by using a codebase that is maintained, and has a community following. In fact, just the opposite.

The original code might be fine for studying, but it is impractical and unwise to choose as a base for new work, when something like ioq3 is available.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to clean all the projects in VS2015, and to the *quake3* project add the following command line agruments:

```
+set sv_pure 0 +set vm_game 0 +set vm_cgame 0 +set vm_ui 0
```

Also, make sure to copy the *baseq3* folder from your Quake 3 arena game into the Quake-III-Arena/code folder.